# How to read multiple txt files into one List with multithread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am learning multithread in Java. To practice, I want do multithread to read three txt files in paralel, adding each line of three files into one List. This is my code:

```
ArrayList<String> allLinesFromFiles= new ArrayList<String>();
Lock blockThread=new ReentrantLock();
Thread t = null;
    for (String file : files) {
        
        t= new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    FileReader fichero;
                    fichero = new FileReader(file);
                    BufferedReader bufferFichero = new BufferedReader(fichero);
                    String line = bufferFichero.readLine();
                    
                    while (line != null) {
                        writeList(line.toLowerCase());
                        line = bufferFichero.readLine();
                    }
            
                    bufferFichero.close();
                    
                }catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Error IO");
                }
            }
            
            private void writeList(String line) {
                blockThread.lock();
                allLinesFromFiles.add(line);
                blockThread.unlock();
            }
        });
        t.start();  
    }
    try {
        t.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Collections.sort(allLinesFromFiles);
```

I used lock/unlocks (ReentrantLock) in the method "writeList" to synchronize because three threads writting in the ArrayList I thought maybe is needed. Is correct? Have I to use CopyOnWriteArrayList instead of ArrayList?

I used join() to wait the finish of three threads but my code dont work correctly.

Comment: You're only calling `join()` on one thread (the last file's thread), so not all threads may be finished when you sort the list.

Comment: You have only one critical issue - you call join() only for the last thread, as Kayaman said. Store all the threads in an array/list while preparation and then call .join() foe each of it in a loop/for each. Don't use AtomicCounters and sleeps as proposed below. Old good .join() works perfect for your case. The second, but minor issue is that you should close FileReader in finally block or use try-with-resource.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way base on your code is to add an `AtomicInteger` count to know if the read Thread is ended or not，and the Main Thread wait for the end:

```java
List<String> files = Arrays.asList("a.txt", "b.txt", "c.txt");
                ArrayList<String> allLinesFromFiles= new ArrayList<String>();
                Lock blockThread=new ReentrantLock();
                AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0); // counter
                Thread t = null;
                for (String file : files) {
                        t= new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                        try {
                                                FileReader fichero;
                                                fichero = new FileReader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(file).getFile());
                                                BufferedReader bufferFichero = new BufferedReader(fichero);
                                                String line = bufferFichero.readLine();

                                                while (line != null) {
                                                        writeList(line.toLowerCase());
                                                        line = bufferFichero.readLine();
                                                }

                                                bufferFichero.close();
                                        }catch (IOException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                                System.out.println("Error IO");
                                        }finally {
                                                count.getAndIncrement(); // counter ++
                                        }
                                }

                                private void writeList(String line) {
                                        blockThread.lock();
                                        allLinesFromFiles.add(line);
                                        blockThread.unlock();
                                }
                        });
                        t.start();
                }
                while (count.intValue() < 3) {
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
                }
                Collections.sort(allLinesFromFiles);
                System.out.println(allLinesFromFiles);
```

But, a better way is:

```java
List<String> filePaths = Arrays.asList("a.txt", "b.txt", "c.txt");
                List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
                filePaths.parallelStream().forEach(filePath -> {
                        try {
                                List<String> strings = Files.readAllLines(
                                        Paths.get(ReadTest.class.getClassLoader().getResource(filePath).toURI()));
                                result.addAll(strings);
                        } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                });
                Collections.sort(result);
                System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: You write concurrently into plain not thread-safe List<String> result = new ArrayList<>()?